# how to use facet in pysolr

Tags: python, pysolr

I have successful built a python search app with pysolr. So far I have used two fields: id and title. now i want to push two different versions of titles; the original and the title after removing the stopwords. any ideas? the following code works:

```
def BuildSolrIndex(solr, trandata):
    tmp = []
    for i, dat in enumerate(trandata):
        if all(d is not None and len(d) > 0 for d in dat):
            d = {}
            d["id"] = dat[0]
            d["title"] = dat[1]
            tmp.append(d)
    solr.add(tmp)
    solr.optimize()
    return solr
```

but this one does not:

```
def BuildSolrIndex(solr, trandata):
    tmp = []
    for i, dat in enumerate(trandata):
        if all(d is not None and len(d) > 0 for d in dat):
            d = {}
            d["id"] = dat[0]
            d["title_org"] = dat[1]
            d["title_new"] = CleanUpTitle(dat[1])
            tmp.append(d)
    solr.add(tmp)
    solr.optimize()
    return solr
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

bellow is the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    solr = BuildSolrIndex(solr, trandata)
  File "...", line 56, in BuildSolrIndex
    solr.add(tmp)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pysolr.py", line 779, in add
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pysolr.py", line 387, in _update
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pysolr.py", line 321, in _send_request
pysolr.SolrError: [Reason: None]
<response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">8</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">ERROR: [doc=...] unknown field 'title_new'</str><int name="code">400</int></lst></response>
```

Comment: What happens to make you say it doesn't work? Do you get an exception?

Comment: yes, that's right. it throws an exception here : `solr.add(tmp)`

Comment: What exception? Please edit your question adding the complete traceback.

Comment: @Faust question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with your Solr schema.xml, as the exception indicates that "title_new" is not recognized as a valid field. This answer may be of assistance to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14400137/1675729

Check to make sure your schema.xml contains a "title_new" field, and that you've restarted the Solr services if necessary. If this doesn't solve your problem, come on back!

Comment: Thanks! But where exactly is this schema located?

Comment: probably it is this one, correct: `../solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml`

Comment: Without knowing your specific Solr implementation I can't say :)